# Cannot find module 'ClientApp/app/app.module'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to import AppModule but I'm having trouble with telling the program where it's located.

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

My app.module is located in project\ClientApp\app as shown in this picture:

[image: structure]

However when I try to import it, it says that the module can't be found:

[image: error]

I also tried to:

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
```

… but the error stays the same.

I'm assuming I'm using the wrong syntax to try and locate it.
How do I properly write the import sentence?

Comment: where are you importing from? that's an important piece of the puzzle

Comment: The file is located here: http://imgur.com/phwpDm5 . Am I missing something?

Comment: so, under `ClientApp/app`? if so, you should change the import path to `./app.module`

Comment: Tried ./app.module and it still gets squiggly underlined.

Comment: let me clarify: by *"where are you importing from?"*, i mean: **which file has the `import` statement in it**? what's its **path**?

Comment: The file where I'm trying to import it is main.ts, which is located in ClientApp\app\components\ships

Comment: awesome. in that case, your import should have the (relative) path: `../../app.module`

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative path to locate your desired module for import.

Assuming you are trying to import `ClientApp/app/app.module` from `ClientApp/app/components/ships/my-other-module`, your import declaration should look like this:

**my-other-module.js**

```
import { AppModule } from '../../app.module';
```

Answer (score -4):

For me i used the whole relative path 
import { AppModule } from '../../../../../../src/app/app.module'; and it worked. Plz try this one.